# Problem with Storing double pointer to a constant double pointer

Tags: c, linux

My pointers are of type 'ab', which is an instance of a struct with members: state, deadline etc.

Shown below is my current code:

```
ab **currProc;                         // double pointer
ab **const runnProc = &(*currProc);
```

When I later update the value of **currProc, even the value of **runnProc changes; which I don't require to happen.

Please note: I cannot change the declaration from `ab **const runnProc = &(*currProc);`  to `const ab** runnProc = &(*currProc);` either, because I modify a member e.g.: `(*runnProc)->state` later.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? currProc and runnProc are pointing to the same object, so it is inevitable that any changes to that object will be seen through both pointers.

Comment: I later want to be able to change what currProc points at without changing runnProc @SvenNilsson

Comment: Do you really need a double pointer for that? Also please note that dereferencing a pointer that does not point to anything is illegal. In your example currProc points nowhere, yet you are using (*currProc).

Comment: In my code currProc does point to a certain instance of ab, so not to worry. And given my position in my code, double pointer is being used.

Comment: No, currProc points to a pointer which points to an instance of ab.

Comment: If you don't want `**runnProc` to change when you change `**currProc`, you'll have to copy `**curProc`, create a new pointer that points to it, and make `runnProc` point to this pointer. There's probably a simpler solution to your problem that involves not using a double pointer at all.

Comment: Yes you are right @SvenNilsson

Comment: Is there a specific way or function to use to copy? @interjay

Comment: @Junaid What do you want currProc to point to?

Comment: @user253751 I want to be able to change what **currProc points to, without changing what **runnProc points at.

Comment: @Junaid Okay but the question was what currProc should point to (i.e. which variable is *currProc) not **currProc. currProc is a pointer to a pointer - that is, it points to a variable and that variable is also a pointer. Which variable would you like it to point to?

Comment: @user253751 does it matter? *currProc already points to an instance of ab anyway.

Comment: @Junaid Of course it matters where a pointer points to! If you have a pointer and don't care where it points to that's like having a house address but not caring whose house it is. And then you tell all your friends "hey, go here for the party" and give them some random stranger's address because you didn't care whose address it was. If currProc points to variable v1 and runnProc also points to variable v1 then obviously *currProc and *runnProc are the same, and the only way you'll ever make them different is by making them point to dfiferent variables.

Comment: I get your point. @user253751
Do u suggest the use of duplicate variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

> ```
> ab **const runnProc = &(*currProc);
> ```

... expresses that the pointer `runnProc` cannot be changed, but it says nothing about whether the `ab *` it points to, if any, or the `ab` *that* points to, if any, can be changed, whether via expressions involving `runnProc` or otherwise.  Moreover, the initialization makes the (unmodifiable) value of `runnProc` be a pointer to the same object that `*currProc` points to, so yes, it follows that if you do not modify pointer `currProc` or `*currProc` between, then

> When I later update the value of **currProc, even the value of **runnProc changes

The two expressions refer to the same object.

Even if you instead declared `runnProc` as

```
const ab **runProc = /* ... */;
```

, that does not mean that the value of `**runProc` will thereafter always be the same.  It just means that the object referenced by the expression `**runProc` cannot be modified *via that expression*.  If the pointed-to object is not itself declared `const`, then it is always possible for it to be modified via a different, non-`const`-qualified lvalue referencing it.

If, as you say, you cannot change how you initialize `runnProc`, and you cannot avoid modifying `**currProc`, at least without first modifying `*currProc`, then that's the end of the story.  Your code must be prepared for the fact that `**runnProc` will change.  No form of `const`-qualification of `runnProc`'s type affects that at all.

#### Update

Possibly you want to create a copy of the value of `**currProc` for `runnProc` to indirectly point to. A naive way to do this might be,

```
ab runnAb = **currProc;     // this is where the copy is made
ab *runnAb_p = &runnAb;     // you need this because you want a double pointer
ab **runnProc = &runnAb_p;  // there doesn't seem to be any need for const-ness here
```

That might be sufficient for your needs, but it is impossible to say for sure without knowing more about type `ab` and how you use it, and also how you use `*currProc`.  In particular, that creates `runnAb` as a *shallow* copy of the initial `**currProc`, so there might then still be aliasing between the objects accessible via the members of `**currProc` and those accessible via the members of `**runnProc`.  Also, it's unclear what you expect to happen when `currProc` or `*currProc` is modified, or whether that's in fact a relevant concern.

There is no one-size-fits-all approach to making copies of objects.

Comment: Is there a way I can make a variable point to what is currently being referenced by 
`**currProc` only. And later not let changing `**curProc`  affect the variable at all. @John Bollinger

Comment: Because I am okay with changing my initializing of runnProc.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to ask, @Junaid, then the answer is "no".  Assigning a pointer to point to an object cannot affect whether that object is modifiable.  You could, however, create an independent *copy* of the object to which `*currProc` initially points, and make `runnProc` point to a pointer to *that*.  But doing so would require more than just a change to how you initialize `runnProc`.

Comment: I want to try this independent copy approach, how exactly would I do that? Because I understand my current implementation of runnProc needs to change. @John Bollinger

Comment: Very well, @Junaid, I have added some comments about that.  But too much is unknown to me here to have any confidence in giving you a detailed prescription.  You need to do some of the work yourself, informed by the details of the context in which you are using this.

Comment: Got around my problem, with the approach you suggested under the Update header. :) Thank you John

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ab* otherprocPtr = (ab*)malloc(sizeof(ab));

ab* currprocPtr = (ab*)malloc(sizeof(ab));
ab* runnprocPtr = currprocPtr; // now pointing to same object

ab** currProc = &currprocPtr;
ab** runnProc = &runnprocPtr;

*currProc =  otherprocPtr; // update one so it points to the other
```

Comment: Okay first of all, 'new' expression does not exist for C right

Comment: Okay, I updated the code but you probably know what I mean anyway :)

Comment: Let me try this approach and see

Comment: I used the approach stated in answer above this answer, thank you anyways :)